# Connecting to a database using a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm

I've started getting into WPF not so long ago.
As I'm in the stage of learning MVVM, I'm using [THIS](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) tutorial.

Following that tutorial I now have a basic project that involves products.
The next thing I want to do, is *learn how to connect to a database and store/retrieve information from it.*

My question is, **what are the available ways to connect to a database? what is the best, efficient way to do it?**

Also, **can WPF applications connect to an hosted mysql database (the ones used for websites)?**

I'm using VS2012 if that makes any difference.

Excuse my newbie-ness! I'm still just a beginner!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes they can, just like any other .NET application: [Connecting to MySQL Database using C# and .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71346/Connecting-to-MySQL-Database-using-C-and-NET) - there's plenty of tutorials online, did you check any?

Comment: Consider using the EntityFramework, it should work with MySql as well, although i never tried that for myself. Search for EntityFramework and MySql.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments, use Entity Framework for simplicity's sake. I want to add that I recommend you take a "code first" approach, because it is easier to start with, and because that's the direction the future releases of EF are headed. I'm using it and it's great.

Comment: -1 What does DB have to do with WPF? Your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Hmm basically, I need to know how to retrieve/store information in a database from my application. I don't know of any other usage so I thought it was clear enough... *editing*

Comment: Your first question can be answered trivially from Google. Your second question can't be answsered, it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: [EF code first with oracle, mysql, etc.](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html#codefirstsample)

At the end, there is download link for a sample.

As for WPF, i would recommend to read some tutorials if you´re not familiar with it. Searching for WPF and EF together will lead to a lot of more or less helpful tutorials and blogs, etc. 
But i would recommend playing around with the Entityframework and the code-first approach first.

Comment: Yep, that's what I WAS doing until now... I think it's about time to get my hands dirty and have some fun with it... EF it is then!

Answer (score 2):

Setting up Entity Framework takes too long + Compatibility issues, thus not efficient.
Use this:

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection
 {
      ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection_String_Name"].ConnectionString
 };

 connection.Open();

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Query_For_What_You_Wanna_Do");
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 connection.Close();
```