# How to use different database systems from windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, database, database-connection

I am developing a WPF application where I need to connect different database management systems like Oracle, MSSQL Server, MySQL and show data using Entity Framework. How can I implement this application so I can choose which database systems I want to connect right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111566/connecting-to-a-database-using-a-wpf-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to MSSQL, you can use SqlConnection. You don't need to download any library. 
If you connect to MySQL, you can use MySqlConnection. 
[Download assembly from here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Connection Example:

```
string conStr = "Data Source:127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog: DatabaseName; uid:username; pwd:password";
SqlConnection conMsSql = new SqlConnection(conStr);
MySqlConnection conMySql = new MySqlConnection(conStr);

private void OpenConnection()
{
    if(conMsSql.state != ConnectionState.Open)
        conMsSql.Open();
    if(conMySql.state != ConnectionState.Open)
        conMySql.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when I have multiple backends to support, which I want to use interchangeably and blindly, here's how I usually think:

1. Is using if / switch statements all over the code acceptable ? If too much repetition, it's not a good solution. ( In your example, if you only have to connect to DB, and only have always the same sql query, it's completely acceptable)
2. Is a simple polymorphism / class inheritance a good idea for encapsulating the backend differences ? However, if it generates too much boiler plate code, it's not a solution complex enough to abstract all the subtleties of the different behaviors depending on the backend vendors.
3. Is there a 3-rd party lib that encapsulates all the vendors to be compatible with ? and which abstracts everything with a nicely-unified interface ?
4. Using the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), let's you do what point 3 could offer you... but you make it yourself, for yourself: Likely much more work, much more bugs than point 3.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ADO.NET for this purpose. The framework provided with classes like SQLClient for SQL Server, OleDb for oracle etc.for connecting and querying purposes

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use App.config file to list your db connection string and call it..

Something like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
<add name="mysqlConnection" connectionString="data source=yourdatasource_ip;initial catalog=yourdbname;user=dbusername;password=dbpassword; default command timeout=120"/>
<add name="sqlConnection" connectionString="data source=yourdatasource_ip;initial catalog=yourdbname;user=dbusername;password=dbpassword; default command timeout=120"/>
<add name="oracleConnection" connectionString="data source=yourdatasource_ip;initial catalog=yourdbname;user=dbusername;password=dbpassword; default command            timeout=120"/>
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>`