# Connecting database from published WPF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have a WPF application that:

- Takes user input, stores it into a database
- Reads from a database and displays it on the screen
- Currently is just using [`SqlConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23279112/4573703) method to execute and query a `SQL Server` database

When deployed, this application will have multiple within network users that should be able to connect to the application and read/write to it as well. Of course, this database is user access controlled, and the end users don't have access to the `SQL Server` instance. The only ways I can think of connecting are:

- Using a generic account that has access to the database and then including that in the connection string.
- Creating a [REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/wpf-rest-web-api-consumption/) to pass requests to the database, bit unsure on details.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API would add a level of complexity and additional infrastructure requirements to your application. It would also add an opportunity to use the application outside your network, so that may be a plus. However, if that's not the anticipated use case, it's probably overkill

Also, REST would still need an account to access the database, so it's not really better than your first idea. Depending on the WPF part, you may also have to change the access to the data (for example, using web service clients instead of EF).

Perhaps you can add your users to the database and give them limited privileges to only access selected tables, views or stored procedures. This can add a fine grained control of who and what on the database level. However, this requires a bit or lot of work, depending on the number of your users.

So, your first idea is the easiest one and can probably be expanded to the separate database accounts for your users, while REST probably requires a bit of additional work and setting up the web server etc.